# VSTO (Word) - Update links on save

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am currently developing a word adding. I need the "Update links on save" in Web Options to be applied.

Details of this setting can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903163

This will allow me to get the absolute reference of files. Does anyone know how to apply this setting programmatically OR retrieve the absolute URL of a file when this is not checked?

Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. The link i provided in my question contains the section "Use absolute hyperlinks in a single document" which states if you place "x" in the Hyperlink base field this document will use absolute file referencing. To get to the property in C#:

```
foreach (DocumentProperty prop in (DocumentProperties)Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties)
{
    if (prop.Name == "Hyperlink base")
    {
        prop.Value = "x";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem, I wanted to keep the relative links at save so the answer from Steven Bruce did not help me. 
This worked for me.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

// Create a word app
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
// Change setting so that hyperlinks do not update on save
DefaultWebOptions WordOptions = winword.DefaultWebOptions();
WordOptions.UpdateLinksOnSave = false; // or true in your case
```